# Collecting Backtracked Solutions in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a trouble with collecting Backtracked solutions in Swi-prolog so my code is :

```
fxd_cell(1,1,2).
fxd_cell(1,3,7).
fxd_cell(1,4,3).
fxd_cell(1,6,1).
fxd_cell(1,8,8).
fxd_cell(2,2,5).
fxd_cell(2,4,6).
fxd_cell(2,5,2).
fxd_cell(2,6,9).
fxd_cell(2,9,4).
fxd_cell(3,1,3).
fxd_cell(3,2,6).
fxd_cell(3,3,9).
fxd_cell(3,6,4).
% snip
fxd_cell(9,7,4).
fxd_cell(9,9,2).


index(_,_).
get_num(X) :- L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], member(X,L).
isEmpty([]):- 1 = 1.
isEmpty([H|_]):- \+ get_num(H),!.

find_Empty(L):-  fail .
find_Empty(L):- get_num(X),get_num(Y),findall(Num,fxd_cell(X,Y,Num),L1),isEmpty(L1),L=        [index(X,Y)|LL].
```

when I call find_Empty(L) the result will show as :

```
L = [index(1, 2)|_G3978]
```

and when I press ";" another solution like :

```
L = [index(1, 5)|_G3978] ;
L = [index(1, 7)|_G3978]
```

is Shown ..
However I want to Make L contains all solution how can i do that  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findall/3`:

```
findall(X, find_Empty(X), L).
```